# Window Close Hook in Xmonad

Tags: xmonad

There's the `manageHook` which is called every time a new window is recognized by Xmonad.

Is there something similar for a window closing hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one does not exist.

However, you can use `handleEventHook` listening for `DestroyWindowEvent` events. (Note, by default, two `DestroyWindowEvent` hooks are produced, one will have ev_window == ev_event, the other will have ev_event = the parent.)